# How handle Transactions and API call in same method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

How handle Transactions and API call in same method?
If API takes long time to get the data from external api or waits till ConnectionTimeout, updateItemPrice will hold the db as method is @Transactional(readOnly = false).
How make method performant so that API call does not create long running Transaction?

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    @Autowired
    private ItemExternalClient itemExternalClient;

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    ... other methods

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Item updateItemPrice(int itemId) {
        Item item = itemRepository.getById(itemId);
        
        //API call to external items client
        ExternalItem externalItem = itemExternalClient.getItemById(id);
        item.setPrice(externalItem.getPrice());
        
        return itemRepository.save(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public Item updateItemPrice(int itemId) {
    //API call to external items client
    int price = getExternalItemPrice(itemId);
    return updateItemPrice(itemId, price);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
int getExternalItemPrice(int id) {
    ExternalItem externalItem = itemExternalClient.getItemById(id);
    return externalItem.getPrice();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
Item updateItemPrice(int itemId, int price) {
    Item item = itemRepository.getById(itemId);
    item.setPrice(price);
    return itemRepository.save(item);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).